# Ok to truncate report_viewed_product_index

Tags: mysql, performance, enterprise-1.13

I was reading through the list of tables that are ok to truncate (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205714/list-of-tables-to-safely-truncate-in-magento)  and I didn't see

```
report_viewed_product_index
```

The table is huge and it takes a very long time to restore the database. Is it safe to truncate this data or at least remove the oldest data?

Comment: Interesting question, btw. I wondered the same some time ago :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As far as I can see/know this table is included in the event `log_log_clean_after`.

If you look under the file `app/code/core/Mage/Reports/etc/config.xml` you will see the following snippet.

```
<events>
    <log_log_clean_after>
        <observers>
            <reports>
                <class>reports/event_observer</class>
                <method>eventClean</method>
            </reports>
        </observers>
    </log_log_clean_after>
</events>
```

This method simply cleans all the report events and then the product viewed and compared tables.

```
public function eventClean(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    /* @var $event Mage_Reports_Model_Event */
    $event = Mage::getModel('reports/event');
    $event->clean();

    Mage::getModel('reports/product_index_compared')->clean();
    Mage::getModel('reports/product_index_viewed')->clean();

    return $this;
}
```

If you make sure you have the logClean cron setup then the reports should also be cleaned up with it.

Comment: Nice answer, David :)

Comment: How to delete in magento 2 programmatically, I am newbie here, Please help me out in report_product_viewed_index table records using module

Answer (score 12):

I put some research in this some time ago as we also had issues with that table.
`report_viewed_product_index` is used for the recently viewed products. **If you don't use this feature: Go and truncate :-)**

If you use the recently views products functionality, check if your cron is set up correct. The entries for visitors that do no more exist in the `log/visitor` table should then be removed automatically at the `log_log_clean_after` event.

The clean method is inherited for `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Product_Index_Viewed` from `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Product_Index_Abstract` where this happens.

```
/**
 * Clean index (visitor)
 *
 * @return Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Product_Index_Abstract
 */
public function clean()
{
while (true) {
    $select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()
        ->from(array('main_table' => $this->getMainTable()), array($this->getIdFieldName()))
        ->joinLeft(
            array('visitor_table' => $this->getTable('log/visitor')),
            'main_table.visitor_id = visitor_table.visitor_id',
            array())
        ->where('main_table.visitor_id > ?', 0)
        ->where('visitor_table.visitor_id IS NULL')
        ->limit(100);
    $indexIds = $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchCol($select);

    if (!$indexIds) {
        break;
    }

    $this->_getWriteAdapter()->delete(
        $this->getMainTable(),
        $this->_getWriteAdapter()->quoteInto($this->getIdFieldName() . ' IN(?)', $indexIds)
    );
}
return $this;
}
```

Comment: not too bad an answer yourself ;)

Comment: Hmm, we have a lot of records with visitor_id is NULL in report_viewed_product_index - it seems that these records will not be removed